# What are disks "MadRiver5M993.iPhone", " Bittersweet6M149.iPh..." as shown by "diskutil list"

Tags: macos, mount, diskutil

When I type `diskutil list`, I see disks I don't recognise:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            2.0 TB     disk0s2
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            DerivedData            *1.1 GB     disk1
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *845.3 MB   disk2
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         30.7 KB    disk2s1
   2:         Apple_Driver_ATAPI                         2.0 KB     disk2s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS MadRiver5M993.iPhone... 845.2 MB   disk2s3
/dev/disk3
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *824.4 MB   disk3
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         30.7 KB    disk3s1
   2:         Apple_Driver_ATAPI                         2.0 KB     disk3s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS MadRiver5M640.iPhone... 824.4 MB   disk3s3
/dev/disk4
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *856.0 MB   disk4
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         30.7 KB    disk4s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Bittersweet6M149.iPh... 856.0 MB   disk4s2
/dev/disk5
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *883.0 MB   disk5
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         30.7 KB    disk5s1
   2:         Apple_Driver_ATAPI                         2.0 KB     disk5s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS MadRiver5M790.iPhone... 883.0 MB   disk5s3
/dev/disk6
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *5.3 MB     disk6
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         30.7 KB    disk6s1
   2:         Apple_Driver_ATAPI                         2.0 KB     disk6s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS Telluride9A407.iPhon... 5.2 MB     disk6s3
```

`/dev/disk0` is my physical HDD and `/dev/disk1` is a ram disk I use with Xcode, however I don't recognise `/dev/disk2` onwards.

They look like they might be related to Xcode/iPhone development in some way, however I've not noticed them before.

Strangely, they don't appear when using the `mount` command:

```
/dev/disk0s2 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1 on /Users/andy/tmp/DerivedData (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, noowners, mounted by andy)
```

**EDIT** Here's a bit info for one of the disks:

```
 $ diskutil info /dev/disk2
   Device Identifier:        disk2
   Device Node:              /dev/disk2
   Part of Whole:            disk2
   Device / Media Name:      Apple UDIF read-only compressed (zlib) Media

   Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)

   Mounted:                  Not applicable (no file system)

   File System:              None

   Content (IOContent):      Apple_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 Disk Image
   SMART Status:             Not Supported

   Total Size:               845.3 MB (845281280 Bytes) (exactly 1650940 512-Byte-Blocks)
   Volume Free Space:        Not applicable (no file system)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          Yes
   Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (no file system)
   Ejectable:                Yes

   Whole:                    Yes
   Internal:                 No
   OS 9 Drivers:             No
   Low Level Format:         Not supported
```

Can anyone explain what they are?

Answer (score 3):

That is what a virtual filesystem (normally a .dmg file) looks like when `hdiutil` mounts the filesystem.

You can simply eject them to clean your mount points as you would to eject any physical disk and the system will clean up the mounts as if you used `hdiutil` to unmount the virtual filesystem:

```
diskutil eject disk2
diskutil eject disk3
diskutil eject disk4
diskutil eject disk5
diskutil eject disk6
```

You could also try using `mdfind` (or spotlight) to locate files with dmg or those names in it or dump the files that diskimages-helper has open:

```
mdfind -name dmg
sudo lsof | grep diskimage
```

The `hdiutil` tool also might be helpful if you want to use it to unmount / mount these disk images in a controlled manner. The files don't have to be dmg, but look for those first and perhaps img or iso as an extension.

Comment: Well I don't see where the .dmg would be mounted from.  I understand how to get rid of them, but I was hoping to find out what they are.  Perhaps the question is better asked on stackoverflow.com...

Comment: A dmg can be mounted from _anywhere_ so I'll edit that into my answer. If you don't know what processes are mounting disk images, it might be hard to track down after the fact. You could reboot and watch. It could be Xcode if you are restoring devices with custom OS builds that you downloaded...

Comment: I have rebooted and the disks have not re-appeared.  Having started Xcode again, they still haven't appeared.  I even started the iOS Simulator, as still nothing.  Weird.  Perhaps they are only there when installing a new version of Xcode?

Comment: Only if you are restoring a device, would an image get downloaded and mounted in my experience. I can confirm that if you click a dmg in finder (or otherwise have them mounted), the lsof command will find it.

Comment: Thanks for the info on `mdfind`; I'll have to wait until they reappear before seeing what these images are.